# How to test for integrated order 2/non-stationary I(2)?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, econometrics, stationarity

How do I apply the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (or alternative) test to determine if a variable is $I(2)$ instead of $I(1)$? Is there functionality for this in `R` language?

My guess would be to apply the following procedure:

- Reject the null hypothesis that $X_t$ is $I(0)$, concluding that $X_t \sim I(d)$ for $d > 0$.
- Test $H_0 : \Delta X_t \sim I(0)$.
- If $H_0$ is rejected, then $X_t \sim I(d)$ for $d > 1$.
- Continue until we isolate $d$.

Comment: Yes, this is the procedure. Only with ADF the null hypothesis is unit root. So you need to accept hypothesis that process is I(1) then that $\Delta X$ is I(1) etc.

Comment: @mpiktas If I use the ADF, then I don't see how I can apply my proposed procedure. Under ADF, if we reject $H_0$ in the first step, then we've concluded that $X_t$ is $I(1)$. It then doesn't make sense to test if $X_t$ is $I(2)$ because the first test has already told us that it's $I(1)$?

Comment: The null for the ADF is the unit root. If you reject null, you reject unit root.